# Access to database is denied, Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

When i try to register new user in my app i get:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'.
```

I basically created new app, made database for app. Changed in env database user info (I use same user for local development for every project , so it has all permissions).

After that i've tried to change alternative choice in database config (even there is not homestead , there was forge) but nothing changed..

For Users, controller, view , etc. I was simply used php artisan `make:auth` and then migrate..

Migration did work, so i don't get it where I made mistake.

Comment: You need to check your user on your database

Comment: I use this same user for database acces in every project in localhost env. So it's all ok with that.

Comment: *"Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'"* says otherwise

Answer (score 1):

In your env file

    `DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_DATABASE=-------(put here your database name);
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=`

Also check your databse.php fileand updated it with proper database connection details.